# Trying to animate a button in polymer

Tags: javascript, css, animation, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to implement a button animation from "hamburger" to an X.

Here's the code I'm using:

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Icon 1 */

 #nav-icon2 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Icon 2 */

#nav-icon2 {
}

#nav-icon2 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #d3531a;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(even) {
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 9px 9px 0;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(odd) {
  left:0px;
  border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(1), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(3), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon2 span:nth-child(5), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(6) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1),#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 7px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 7px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(3) {
  left: -50%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(4) {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
  left: 5px;
  top: 29px;
}

#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: 29px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div on-tap="flip" id="nav-icon2">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Polymer({
  is: "flip-button",

  flip: function() {
    console.log("here");
    console.log(this.classList.contains("open"));
    this.classList.toggle("open");
  }
});
```

In the console, I can see the logs I put in. I also checked the elements, and I can see the `open` class going on and off, but no animation. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're applying the `open` class to the Polymer element itself (i.e., `this.classList.toggle('open')`, where `this` is the Polymer element), while the animation's CSS selector is targeting `nav-icon2` (i.e., `#nav-icon2.open`).

The quickest fix is to apply the class to `nav-icon2` (via [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding)):

```
// this.classList.toggle("open");  // DON'T DO THIS

this.$['nav-icon2'].classList.toggle("open");
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: "flip-button",

    flip: function() {
      console.log("here");
      console.log(this.classList.contains("open"));
      this.$['nav-icon2'].classList.toggle("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <flip-button></flip-button>

  <dom-module id="flip-button">
    <template>
      <style>
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        /* Icon 1 */

        #nav-icon2 {
          width: 60px;
          height: 45px;
          position: relative;
          margin: 50px auto;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
          -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
          transition: .5s ease-in-out;
          cursor: pointer;
        }


        /* Icon 2 */

        #nav-icon2 {
        }

        #nav-icon2 span {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          height: 9px;
          width: 50%;
          background: #d3531a;
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
          -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
          transition: .25s ease-in-out;
        }

        #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(even) {
          left: 50%;
          border-radius: 0 9px 9px 0;
        }

        #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(odd) {
          left:0px;
          border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px;
        }

        #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(1), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(2) {
          top: 0px;
        }

        #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(3), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(4) {
          top: 18px;
        }

        #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(5), #nav-icon2 span:nth-child(6) {
          top: 36px;
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1),#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(1) {
          left: 5px;
          top: 7px;
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(2) {
          left: calc(50% - 5px);
          top: 7px;
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(3) {
          left: -50%;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(4) {
          left: 100%;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(5) {
          left: 5px;
          top: 29px;
        }

        #nav-icon2.open span:nth-child(6) {
          left: calc(50% - 5px);
          top: 29px;
        }
      </style>
      <div on-tap="flip" id="nav-icon2">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zZvyea?editors=1010)

Comment: Ohhhh I see, thank you so much that fixed it, and that makes so much sense now.

Comment: @L.Lasiter No problem :)